# Add additional param to post data using jqGrid when adding new row with modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to add additional dynamic parameter to jqGrid's `POST` data when I'm adding new record with modal form.

I tried:

```
$('#table').setPostData({group: id});
$('#table').setPostDataItem('group', id);
$('#table').setGridParam('group', id);
```

and nothing worked out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [editData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) parameter of the [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method. In the most cases you use [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) not directly, but using Navigator. In the case you can define [editData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) as the part of `prmEdit` or `prmAdd` of the [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition):

```
$('#table').jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
                   {/*navGrid options*/},
                   {/*Edit options*/
                       editData: {
                           group: function() {
                               return id;
                           }
                       }
                   }
});
```

One more option is the [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events), [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) or [beforeSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) method. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364343/jqgrid-sending-edit-data/3364759#3364759) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246555/how-to-pass-additional-postdata-into-an-add-record-function-jqgrid-mvc-net/5252503#5252503).

Comment: thanks, it helped me a lot, but actually I set it as add options param

Comment: @Teneff: You are welcome. The setting of the "Add" option works exactly in the same way (the next `prmAdd` parameter of `navGrid`), but I am sure you found this already yourself.

Comment: @Oleg: Can we call navGrid in runtime so I can add data to the editData field? Would it overwrite any preset settings in navigator?

Comment: @Quincy: You can't overwrite the `navGrid` parameters with the second cal of `navGrid`. If you would use `editData: myEditData`, where `myEditData` is an object (defined at least as `var myEditData={};`) you will be able to add, modify or remove the properties of `myEditData`.

Comment: @Oleg: Do you mean I must pass an object as parameter in order to add new data into editData? Because I was trying to add something to editdata by putting {newdata:'something'} as the editData param when I call navGrid the 2nd time but seems nothing has changed.

Comment: @Quincy: Yes! In must be a variable with the object (like `myEditData` see above) as a value instead of inline syntax `{...}`. In the case the `navGrid` will receive **the reference** to the object `myEditData`. So I hope (but not tested myself) that you will be able to modify `myEditData` and the `navGrid` will use it in the modified form.

Comment: @Oleg: Ok thanks I will give it a try. If you have time please check out my other question (probably related) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452368/retrieving-grid-in-form-editing-events-in-jqgrid

Answer (score 8):

You can add additional dynamic parameter to jqGrid's POST data

```
$j("#listsg11").jqGrid({
    url: "/summary_reports",   
    postData: {department:"value1", score_r1:"value2", designation:"value3" },
    mtype: 'POST',
    datatype: "xml",
    height: 250,
    width: '100%', .... and so on
```

This method appends values with default params (used by jqGrid) with call.