# Passing extra data to jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I've been trying to figure out how to pass additional information when adding a new record to my jqGrid.  I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364343/jqgrid-sending-edit-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184399/add-additional-param-to-post-data-using-jqgrid-when-adding-new-row-with-modal-for), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246555/how-to-pass-additional-postdata-into-an-add-record-function-jqgrid-mvc-net) just to list a few.  All pretty much say the same thing.  I should be able to use editData to pass additional info.

Here are my add parameters:

> ```
>     addSettings = {                                     
>         recreateForm: true,
>         width: 400,
>         mtype: "POST",                                  
>         jqModal: true,
>         reloadAfterSubmit: false,
>         savekey: [true, 13],
>         closeOnEscape: true,
>         closeAfterAdd: true,
>         editData: { SomeExtraData: function () { return $('#header_id').val(); } },
>         onclickSubmit: onclickSubmitLocal
>       };
> ```

The record that I'm trying to add is a detail record and it has to have the id from the header; ie header_id.  When I check the data that is being sent to the web service I don't see any additional information.

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Save/AddDetail", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string AddDetail(string Id, string Step_Number, string Step_Description, string oper, string id)
```

I've tried putting an additional parameter in my web service but it always is undefined.  I've tried returning just a string value, one that isn't obtained, and it's the same thing.

Thank you again for any help and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have the problem in the part of your code which you don't posted here. I suppose that you use `JSON.stringify` inside of `serializeRowData`. The `JSON.stringify` don't execute methods of `editData`. Se you should modify your implementation of `serializeRowData` like I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344310/using-jqgrids-inline-editing-with-restful-urls) or originally for the `postData` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810885/postdata-not-passing-any-parameters/5811359#5811359).