# editdata jqgrid transfer data edit

Tags: jqgrid

Here is code my jqgrid editing  through form.

```
  $("#DataEnergy").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagergrid',
    {}, //options
     {editdata: { id_res: $('#resurs').val(), id_obj: readCookie('id_obj')} },// add options
     {editdata: { id_res: $('#resurs').val(), id_obj: readCookie('id_obj')} }, // edit options
     {editdata: { id_res: $('#resurs').val(), id_obj: readCookie('id_obj')}  }, // del options
     {} // search options
     );
```

When editing, the data the  editdata must be sent in the post request.
Why is not there why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use correct names of parameters: [editData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) and [delData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2) (the case is very important in JavaScript).

The next problem is that the call of `navGrid` will be executed **once**, but you want probably to have the values of `$('#resurs').val()` and `readCookie('id_obj')` at the moment of editing/ading/deliting. To fix the problem you can use *function* (methods) inside of `editData` and `delData`:

```js
var myData = {
        id_res: function () { return $('#resurs').val(); },
        id_obj: function () { return readCookie('id_obj'); }
    };

$("#DataEnergy").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagergrid',
    {}, // navGrid options
    { editData: myData }, // add options
    { editData: myData }, // edit options
    { delData: myData },  // del options
);
```

For more information see some other old answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184668/315935), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252503/315935), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364759/315935)